# Use static value while v-model is changing it

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, laravel-blade, v-model

I need to show 'product.upc' in label tag without change (static, the same value always) while v-model is changing the value by input.

```
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <label class="input-group-text p-0">@{{ product.upc }}</label>
   </div>
   <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" v-model="product.upc">
```

Comment: Could you please explain what static value you want to assign to the label if the v-model is changing it? Any example?

Comment: @NehaSoni For exemple, I have '8' in product.upc and I wrote '9' in input, so I'm asking if there is some atribute/function of vue that allow to see '8'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` is a two-way binding that will surely update wherever it is being used, so use another variable for your label instead.

For example, on the mounted hook, you can set the initial value of `product.upc` in another data variable and use that as your label.

`On Js side-`

```
data() {
  return {
    label: null,
    product: {
      upc: "something",
    }
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.label = product.upc
}
```

`On the template side-`

```
<div class="input-group-prepend">
  <label class="input-group-text p-0">@{{ label }}</label>
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" v-model="product.upc">
```